# How to create PDF in dotnet Core on app deployed on Azure App service?

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation, azure-web-app-service, wkhtmltopdf

I developped a dotnet core application. In one of my process I need to generate a PDF file.
I try some packages and I choose the DinkToPdf package.

Here is my configuration in my startup file:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```

Then when I want to generate a pdf I load the external binaries (I stored the binaries libwkhtmltox.dll and libwkhtmltox.so in /lib/x64 with Build Action set to Content and Copy Always to put them in the bin folder)):

```
string libPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"lib/{architectureFolder}/libwkhtmltox" + fileEx);   
context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(libPath);
```

The LoadUnmanagedLibrary function:

```
public class CustomAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
public IntPtr LoadUnmanagedLibrary(string absolutePath)
{
    return LoadUnmanagedDll(absolutePath);
}
protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(String unmanagedDllName)
{
    return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(unmanagedDllName);
}

protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

This process works great in my local Windows but when I deploy my app in an Azure App Service (B1 plan, but I also tried with S1) with Linux I get the following exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibwkhtmltox: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked the binaries, they are well copied to the bin folder.
I know there was [a time](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#pdf-generation-from-html) where loading such libraries in Azure App services was blocked but it looks like this is authorized now.

Do you guys have any idea on this issue?

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Dorian

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows in App Service, the Windows sandbox has restrictions for some GDI APIs. Some PDF engines work but for those engines that require more advanced GDI APIs to work, they will be blocked.

However, one possibility is to use Windows Containers on Azure App Service in which you won't have any sandbox restriction as the Windows Container is the sandbox.

Here you can follow the quickstart to run a Windows Container in App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

If you are targeting Linux on App Service, then you will run within a Linux Container. You can try creating a custom Linux Container and deploy it to App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker

Comment: I am targeting Linux. If I create a Linux container to run my program in Azure App Service B1, what should I add to the Linux container to allow the creation of PDF?
I also investigated to do the pdf creation in an Azure function but that looks not possible as well in a consumption plan.

Comment: Since you are running in App Service Linux, I recommend to open a support incident:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/3

Per this link, there isn't an easy way to get the lib libwkhtmltox.so file to a docker image.